# Angular 6 *ngSwitchCase Not Working

Tags: angular6

Example: I'm using a `div` container and when I run the code, what I only get
         is the switch default value.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
template: `  
          <div [ngSwitch]="toy_color">
             <div *ngSwitchCase="'red'"> RED </div>
             <div *ngSwitchCase="'blue'">  BLUE </div>
             <div *ngSwitchCase="'Yellow'"> YEllOW </div>
             <div *ngSwitchDefault> Pick Again </div>
          </div>

          `
styles: []
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

 public toy_color:"red";

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: Try editing your post to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below line from your code is incorrect.

```
public toy_color:"red";
```

You are not assigning value to toy_color. You should change your code either with it's type or you can directly assign value to variable as below.

1. With assigning type

> public toy_color: string = "red";

2. Directly assign value

> public toy_color = "red";

I have created one [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qhaly?file=src/app/app-test.component.ts) for your reference.

Comment: Nice to hear that it resolved your issue. Can you please up vote the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `toy_color` is undefined. Change it to the following line:

```
public toy_color: string = "red";
```

or

```
public toy_color = "red";
```